# CMake QtCreator invalid project tree

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I have a problem and 
could not find the answer in Web.
I have a project described in CMake (in attached file). 
When I open it in QtCreator, then tree of project is invalid. 
All project files are on the same hierarchy level 
(qml file which is a resource for example) and in the project 
tree displays many files: for example Qt5CoreConfig.cmake, 
Qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake etc. 
When I try to open this files (Qt5CoreConfig.cmake, Qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake etc.) 
QtCreator shows me error dialog where set invalid path to this file.

How can I get rid of the presence in the project tree files 
Qt5CoreConfig.cmake, Qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake and so on?

And how do I get the resource files were in the child 
tree node for qrc file and not on the same level with it?

Comment: Please show your code inline. You cannot attach projects like that on this site.

Comment: http://uploads1.cagoi.com/download/4/1/54732c3eb70bd11813eb3024/5Su8NOrCX6Gi7FstzFDFPQ/0/png/2014-11-24%2015-47-40%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0.png